# Antd design component Avatar.Group throws error

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd, avatar, ant-design-pro

Currently trying to use Avatar.Group in React (https://ant.design/components/avatar/).

It states that the Antd Version I have is 4.5.2 (4.5.0+ for avatar.group functionality) for my package.json

I receive this error:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I've already imported the Avatar library, along with a multitude of other libraries:

```
import { Avatar, Button .....} from 'antd';
```

Right now, in JSX, I am testing the example shown:

```
    <Avatar.Group>
      <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />
      <Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: '#f56a00' }}>K</Avatar>
      <Tooltip title="Ant User" placement="top">
        <Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: '#87d068' }} icon={<UserOutlined />} />
      </Tooltip>
      <Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: '#1890ff' }} icon={<AntDesignOutlined />} />
    </Avatar.Group>
```

A note is that even when I don't have anything in between

```
  <Avatar.Group> </Avatar.Group>
```

gives the same error as well

Package.lock.json and package.json files:

https://justpaste.it/8m3zz

Comment: so would you please show some code for more details?

Comment: Yeah, code where you're importing Avatar component would be nice. Check if you're importing it like so: ```import { Avatar } from 'antd'```

Comment: Apologies, all I have updated my attempts

Comment: Would you mind showing your package.json and check your `package.lock.json` (or `yarn.lock`) for your antd version ? It looks like you're using an old version of Antd which isn't exporting `Avatar.Group`

Comment: Thanks for responding-- really apprecaite you all. I've updated my package.json + package.lock json.
It DOES look like it's not outdated (but would appreciate a quick look), I was curious do you happen to know how I Could update package.lock json accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a classic error when you're importing a component incorrectly.

From what you've shown, there is no error in the component that is using Avatar, and not an issue with the Avatar component and/or antd library itself.

So, if you're getting this error after implementing this new component, I'd check how you're importing it.

Say you you're working on a component called `UserAvatar`

```
import React from "react";
import { Avatar, Tooltip } from "antd";
import { UserOutlined, AntDesignOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const UserAvatar = (_) => {
  return (
    <Avatar.Group>
      (...)
    </Avatar.Group>
  );
};

export default UserAvatar;
```

Now, say you're importing this component from `App.js`

```
import { Comp } from "./Comp";
```

Since the component is being exported as default, you should use:

```
import Comp from "./Comp";
```

There is a lot of guessing in how you're actually importing/exporting por components. It could even be another unrelated component. But since I don't have the full source code and got this error many times before, I'd recommend using the tip I gave you above to check how you import your custom components.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I've seen several answers to other asks for similar issues. I'm looking at using Avatar.Group component specifically-- directly through importing Avatar component. Based on the docs, it seems like all I need to do currently is import the Avatar component : 

import { Avatar } from 'antd' . At the moment, it seems like the package-lock.json isn't updated is my guess or some part is not updated. If you could shed some insight how I could update it, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Aren't you importing like that already? I wouldn't check antd but more on how you're importing other stuff. Try to isolate your error. [Here is a sandbox to reproduce the error](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-zhukovsky-4v2ry?file=/src/App.js). Also, try removing Avatar completely and use an empty div. What happens?

Comment: Thanks for this-- I was able to get it working. Nicholas thank you so much. I really appreciate it